# AJAX Calls with Text Links

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make POST Ajax calls when users click on text links.

One way to do it is to create many forms and make the submit button a text link. Then with jQuery I will fetch the variables from the form and submit them with Ajax.

This will create something like the following:

```
<form><input type="hidden" name="unique-id" value="1"><a href="" class="submitForm"></form>
<form><input type="hidden" name="unique-id" value="2"><a href="" class="submitForm"></form>
<form><input type="hidden" name="unique-id" value="3"><a href="" class="submitForm"></form>
```

Now with jQuery I will use .click() Event handler and send a POST request with the "unique-id" value (from the scope in which the link click was from).

It looks very complicated and messy and I was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Thanks

Joel

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a form to do an Ajax post, You feed the data into the Ajax call itself:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
  dataType: dataType
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the "unique-id" as an id for the links and use that id when posting.

```
<a id="1" href="#">Link</a>
<a id="2" href="#">Foo</a>
<a id="3" href="#">ASDF</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("a").click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: "unique-id=" + $(evt.target).attr("id"),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("done");
                }
            });
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Ajaxify Jquery plugin](http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/demo.php) using the new the Forms submit feature its very easy to use and clean